# Changing the position of Kendo UI Validator

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-validator

I have tried to change the position of Kendo UI Validator in my project, but changing the values of the related properties in the related kendo css files (i.e. display: inline-block;) not solved the problem yet. So, how can I change the  position from below to the right of a control as shown on the attached figure? Thanks in advance for your consideration.

[image]
**Html View (rendered):**

```
<label for="Name">Name</label>

<span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox"><span class="k-numeric-wrap k-expand-padding k-state-disabled">
<input type="text" value="" name="Name" maxlength="30" id="Name" data-val-required="Required field" 
data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-zA-Z \.X]+$" data-val-regex="Please check the value" data-val-maxlength-max="25" 
data-val-maxlength="The field Name must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '25'." data-val="true" 
class="letters_onlyk-formatted-value k-input"></span><span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Name" 
class="field-validation-valid"></span></span>

<span class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg field-validation-error" data-for="Name" 
data-valmsg-for="Name" id="Name_validationMessage" role="alert"><span class="k-icon k-warning"> </span>Required field</span>
```

**Css:**

```
.k-widget.k-tooltip-validation {
    background-color: #FFF4C9;
    border-color: #FFE79E;
    color: #635145;
}

span.k-tooltip {
    border-width: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 5px 1px 6px;
    position: static;
}

.k-tooltip {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    min-width: 20px;
    padding: 4px 5px 4px 6px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 12000;
}
```

**View (razor):**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Multiplier", FormMethod.Post,
new { id = "addForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="container">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Person</legend>
            <section>
                <div class="legend-left">

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Term)
                    <br />
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                    @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.WhoIsOnline)
                    <br />
                    //... deleted for brevity
                </div>
            </section>
        </fieldset>  

            @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                .Name("submitbtn")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "submit", @class = "k-primary k-button k-button-icontext" })
                .Content("Save")
            )
    </div>
}
```

**Update:**

After applying "@Html.ValidationMessageFor" the validation messages appears as shown below:

[image]

Comment: You need to show your markup

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vetawiyudo/1/

Comment: @TarekNajem: Many thanks for your reply. When I tried to copy that code to my view it worked. However, my view is razor and when I copy my code to that page it did not work. Could you have a look at my code and how to use your html code as razor code on my view? Is there a razor format of that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to place ValidationMessageFor after TextBoxFor. Your code should be the following :

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.WhoIsOnline)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Term)
```

In css don't change positions or display attribute, just change colors

And don't forget:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").kendoValidator()
  });
</script>
```

If you want a custom template :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").kendoValidator(
    {
        errorTemplate: "<span class='required'>#=message#</span>"
    });
</script>
```

More info :
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/validation

Comment: Thanks for reply. However the validation messages cannot be aligned. Is it possible to align them for different type of inputs? If no, shall I use jquery validation instead of kendo validator?

Comment: @H.Johnson No u can do a custom template, check my edit

Comment: Hi Tarek. Although the same method and `errorTemplate` can be applied all the inputs such as `Kendo DropdownList`, `TextBox`, etc. it does not work with `Kendo Editor`. I have not found an example on the web for days regarding to `Kendo Editor` validation. Any idea? Could you help pls?